# How can I fix this error installing packages in R

Tags: r, install.packages

I have taken a couple basic courses of R before and want to continue learning about it. Nevertheless, a few month ago I had to restore my computer (an hp with Windows 8) from zero and I installed one of the lastests versions of R (do not remember the specific one) and Rstudio, and when I tried to install packages (mostly, I have been trying with the package dplyr but similar messages are returned with any package I have tried)

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

it retrieved an error saying the package was built (or something like that) for an older version (3.2.2), therefore I changed the version to 3.2.2. I tried to install the package once again with the same code and retrieved the next error (after a lot of "trying URL" messages):

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\Víctor\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYRSybZ\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘R6’, ‘BH’
* installing *source* package 'R6' ...
** package 'R6' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Vmctor/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/R6/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  no se puede abrir la conexión
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'R6'
* removing 'C:/Users/Víctor/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/R6'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Víctor\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\VCTOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYRSybZ/downloaded_packages/R6_2.2.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘R6’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'BH' ...
** package 'BH' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Vmctor/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  no se puede abrir la conexión
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'BH'
* removing 'C:/Users/Víctor/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Víctor\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\VCTOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYRSybZ/downloaded_packages/BH_1.65.0-1.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘BH’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\Víctor\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYRSybZ\downloaded_packages’
```

I noticed part of the error message contained different spellings of the library path, like C:/Users/Vmctor... and C:\Users\VCTOR~1

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Víctor/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"
```

Given that the directory contained the character "í", I thought this was originating the issue, so I created a new user to have a new path without accents

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/victor2/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"
```

I tried installing the package in this new user and this time the message returned did not mention the file path, in short, the retrieved message contains the next (after "trying URL" messages):

```
Binaries will be installed
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘rlang’
  These will not be installed
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\victor2\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpao93L4\downloaded_packages
```

and if I try to use the package this comes up:

```
> library(dplyr)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
there is no package called ‘DBI’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’
```

Does anyone know what the issue is or could tell me where to find information about it?

Thank you.

Comment: how about: 

    install.packages("dplyr",dependencies=TRUE)

Comment: When you do `install.package`, specifying the `lib` might work since the issue seems to related to location.  I'd first try `lib =  "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"` since it is in the search path.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your case but if you are compiling C/C++/FORTRAN code on Windows you will need [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/index.html).